# Pivoted data with a column describing some function of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to pivot some data such that I retrieve (1) the total of some measurement for two+ groups, and then (2) that measurement divided by the # of observations in that group. I have achieved (1) but not (2). Below is an example output I desire:

```
  grouping measurement_total group_size  mean
1        1               301         60   5.0
2        2               215         40   5.4
```

Let some data be:

```
> grouping <- c(1,2,1,1,2)
> measurement <- sample(rnorm(1,10),100, replace=TRUE)
> dataframe <- cbind(grouping, measurement)
```

To create the pivot, I used aggregate. I then used a cbind to get the # of observations per group:

```
> aggregate(cbind(measurement,1) ~ grouping, data=dataframe, FUN=sum)

 grouping measurement V2
1        1         301 60
2        2         215 40
```

I now need to create "V3" which would be { measurement / V2 } such that I achieve the result. NB I can get the mean only by using FUN=mean, but this means I cannot also get the group size.

```
> aggregate(cbind(measurement,1) ~ grouping, data=dataframe, FUN=mean)


  grouping V2(# obs.) mean
1        1         1  5.0
2        2         1  5.4
```

What are some options for achieving this simply, ideally with a single line? I.e. I could obtain the two tables separately and merge the two, but it's a little long-winded.

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to do this fairly easily

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe <- data.frame(dataframe) # Convert to dataframe

dataframe %>%
  group_by(grouping) %>%
  mutate(measurement_total = sum(measurement)) %>%
  mutate(group_size = length(measurement)) %>%
  mutate(mean = mean(measurement)) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1) %>%
  select(-measurement)
```

Of course, the easy way to do it in base R would be:

```
df <- aggregate(cbind(measurement,1) ~ grouping, data=dataframe, FUN=sum)
df$mean <- df$measurement/df$V2
```

But if you're going to be doing dataframe manipulation, it might be a good idea to get into `dplyr`